# A language in which everything compiles

Tags: programming-languages, metaprogramming

I'm trying to do some research for a new project, and I need to create objects dynamically from random data.
For this to work, I need a language / compiler that doesn't have problems with weird uncompilable code lying around.

Basically, I need the random code to compile (or be interpreted) as much as possible - Meaning that the uncompilable parts will be ignored, and only the compilable parts will create the objects (which could be ran).

Object Oriented-ness is not a must, but is a very strong advantage.

I thought of ASM, but it's very messy, and I'd probably need a more readable code

Thanks!

Comment: Can you clarify: what would be the point of uncompilable code?  I'm not seeing a use case here.

Comment: *sorry for the pun* Can I suggest perl? It gets close to the requirements :D just an  amusing story: Once I received a `.pl` code. I tried to run it with perl and got 4 errors. I looked into it and it was prolog. Around 5000 lines of code...

Comment: I'm testing random changes on the source code. Some may alter the code so it won't compile. Even though, I need to compile the code and test the functionality of the altered code

Comment: @yi_H Perl is definitely an option. I will need to learn Perl for it, but it's about time :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you're doing something very much like [genetic programming](http://reddit.honestbleeps.com/); even if you aren't, GP has to solve some of the same problems—using randomness to generate valid programs.  The approach to this that is typically used is to work with a syntax tree: rather than storing `x + y * 3 - 2`, you store something like the following:

[image: A sample syntax tree.]

Then, instead of randomly changing the syntax, one can randomly change nodes in the tree instead.  And if `x` should randomly change to, say, `+`, you can statically know that this means you need to insert two children (or not, depending on how you define `+`).

A good choice for a language to work with for this would be any Lisp dialect.  In a Lisp, the above program would be written `(- (+ x (* y 3)) 2)`, which is just a linearization of the syntax tree using parentheses to show depth.  And in fact, Lisps expose this feature: you can just as easily work with the object `'(- (+ x (* y 3)) 2)` (note the leading quote).  This is a three-element list, whose first element is `-`, second element is another list, and third element is `2`.  And, though you might or might not want it for your particular application, there's an `eval` function, such that `(eval '(- (+ x (* y 3)) 2))` will take in the given list, treat it as a Lisp syntax tree/program, and evaluate it.  This is what makes Lisps so attractive for doing this sort of work; Lisp syntax is basically a reification of the syntax-tree, and if you operate at the syntax-tree level, you can work on code as though it was a value.  Lisp won't help you read `/dev/random` as a program directly, but with a little interpretation layered on top, you should be able to get what you want.

I should also mention, though I don't know anything about it (not that I know much about ordinary genetic programming) the existence of [linear genetic programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_genetic_programming).  This is sort of like the assembly model that you mentioned—a linear stream of very, very simple instructions.  The advantage here would seem to be that if you are working with `/dev/random` or something like it, the amount of interpretation needed is very small; the disadvantage would be, as you mentioned, the low-level nature of the code.

Comment: That actually sounds like a more natural solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if this is what you're looking for, but any programming language can be made to function this way.  For any programming language P, define the language P<sub>always</sub> as follows:

- If p is a valid program in P, then p is a valid program in P<sub>always</sub> whose meaning is the same as its meaning in P.
- If p is **not** a valid program in P, then p is a valid program in P<sub>always</sub> whose meaning is the same as a program that immediately terminates.

For example, I could make the language C++<sub>always</sub> so that this program:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    cout << "Hello, world!" << endl;
}
```

would compile as "Hello, world!", while this program:

```
Hahaha!  This isn't legal C++ code!
```

Would be a legal program that just does absolutely nothing.

To solve your original problem, just take any OOP language like Java, Smalltalk, etc. and construct the appropriate Java<sub>always</sub>, Smalltalk<sub>always</sub>, etc. language from it.  Again, I'm not sure if this is at all what you're looking for, but it could be done very easily.

Alternatively, consider finding a grammar for any OOP language and then using that grammar to produce random syntactically valid programs.  You could then filter those programs down by using the P<sub>always</sub> programming language for that language to eliminate syntactically but not semantically valid programs.

Comment: Thanks for you reply, how could this be done? (technically, I mean) How can you compile bad code?

Comment: You can always try running the compiler, then looking at the exit code from the program.  If it returns with an error, feed into the compiler a known valid program (in C, for example, something like `int main(){}`).  Otherwise, just use the output program from the first run.

Comment: Sorry for nagging, but how could you do this if random parts of the code are problematic? I mean, I could have `class CObject {int iMember; asdas }` and I'd need it to compile without the asdas

Comment: If you have a grammar for the language, then you would never end up generating a string like the one above, since nothing could legally go where `asdas` is right now.  The advantage of the approach is that it always generates syntactically valid programs, filtering out those that aren't semantically valid.

Comment: The changes in the code will be random, so I can't really trust to get anything from the language grammar. Though I haven't thought about using a grammar for making the changes in the first place. Maybe this is a better way. Thanks!

Comment: @templatetypedef: I can see a parallel of that in CSS, where the parser ignores CSS rules that it doesn't support or are invalid.

Answer (score 0):

Divide the ASCII byte values into 9 classes (division modulo 9 would help). Then assign then to Brainfuck codewords (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brainfuck). Then interpret as Brainfuck.

There you go, any sequence of ASCII characters is a program. Not that it's going to do anything sensible...  This approach has a much better chance, compared to templatetypedef's answer, to get a *nontrivial* program from a random byte sequence.

Comment: I was wondering if someone was going to mention brainfuck. :-)  I could be wrong about this, but wouldn't this not necessarily work, since you need to have `[` and `]` balanced?

Comment: Yeah, they have to match. Then use 7 character classes, eliminate loops altogether.

Comment: When composing a program, count the [] characters. When done, attach the required number of ]'s at the end or ['s in the beginning. Or disallow unmatched ]'s. There are ways around the balancing requirement.

Answer (score 0):

**Text Editors**

You could try feeding random character strings to an editor like Emacs or VI.  Many (most?) characters will perform an editing action but some will do nothing (other than beep, perhaps).  You would have to ensure that the random code mutator never generates the character sequence that exits the editor.  However, this experience would be much like programming a Turing machine -- the code is not too readable.

**Mathematica**

In Mathematica, undefined symbols and other expressions evaluate to themselves, without error.  So, that language might be a viable choice if you can arrange for the random code mutator to always generate well-formed expressions.  This would be readily achievable since the basic Mathematica syntax is trivial, making it easy to operate on syntactic units rather than at the character level.  It would be even easier if the mutator were written in Mathematica itself since expression-munging is Mathematica's forte.  You could define a mini-language of valid operations within a Mathematica package that does not import the system-defined symbols.  This would allow you to generate well-formed expressions to your heart's content without fear of generating a dangerous expression, like `DeleteFile[FileNames["*.*", "/", Infinity]]`.

Answer (score -1):

I believe **Common Lisp** should suit your needs. I always have some code in my SLIME/Emacs session that wouldn't compile. You can always tweak things, redefine functions in run-time. It is actually very good for prototyping.

A few years ago it took me quite a while to learn. But nowadays we have quicklisp and everything is so much easier.

Here I describe my development environment:
[Install lisp on my linux machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6546834/install-lisp-on-my-linux-machine/6548692#6548692)

PS: I want to give an example, where Common Lisp was useful for me:
Up to maybe 2004 I used to write small programs in C (the keep it simple Unix way).

The last 3 years I had to get lots of different hardware running. Motorized stages, scientific cameras, IO cards.

The cameras turned out to be quite annoying. Usually you have to cool them down to -50 degree celsius or so and (in some SDKs) they don't like it when you close them. But this
is exactly how my C development cycle worked: write (30s), compile (1s), run (0.1s), repeat.

Eventually I decided to just use Common Lisp. Often it is straight forward to define the foreign function interfaces to talk to the SDKs and I can do this without ever leaving the running Lisp image. I start the editor in the morning define the open-device function, to talk to the device and after 3 hours I have enough of the functions implemented to set gain, temperature, region of interest and obtain the video.

Then I can often put the SDK manual away and just use the camera.

I used the same interactive programming approach when I have to parse some webpage or some weird XML.

Comment: I don't see how this answers the question.  This seems to be more of an argument that the OP should be using Common Lisp to do prototyping than an explanation as to how Common Lisp could be used to generate code that will always compile.  Can you elaborate on how this is relevant?

Comment: I interpreted the question that the OP wants to prototype things. Obviously Common Lisp won't 'compile' broken code. But interpretation is always possible in the way I described.